# Running Facebook Connect on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, api, facebook

I can't run facebook connect on localhost.
I am using app-engine on pydev.
I configured the site in facebook to : http://localhost:8080
but it returns an error :

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: next is not owned by the application.
```

Is there a way to work with facebook on localhost?

Thanks,
Gavriel

Comment: what part of facebook connect are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Set both your Site URL and Post-Authorize Redirect URL to http://localhost:8080/

Also, if you're using Internet Explorer, see here:

[Facebook Connect / Graph - problems in Internet Explorer with fb:login dialog (not closing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952795/facebook-connect-graph-problems-in-internet-explorer-with-fblogin-dialog-no/3389353#3389353)

I found that using http://127.0.0.1:8080 in the browser instead of http://localhost:8080/ fixed a problem I was having in IE.

Comment: +1 Although I don't see a "Post-Authorize Redirect URL" in my app settings.

Comment: @Muhd: On the 'my apps' page, select the app, then click 'edit settings', then select 'facebook integration' on the left. The 'post-authorize redirect URL' is at the bottom of the 'canvas' section.

Comment: 'Bookmark URL' is the bottom option in my canvas section: http://ScrnSht.com/hzmbcs Nevermind the inverted colors.

Comment: Interesting - according to this forum post it looks as though that option may have been removed for newer apps? http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=71434

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and have tried the solution listed above. Do you have any other advice please?

Comment: Hi @PhilHudson, more recently I've found that the only thing which works in IE is http://127.0.0.1/ (I presume Facebook have changed something since I first looked into this). So you have to set app engine to run on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the issue arises because of IE security settings. I fixed it by setting the local intranet zone (i.e. localhost) enhanced security checkbox, same as internet zone.